# Change Channelname with youtubeAPI

Tags: java, python, web-scraping, youtube, youtube-api

I want to change my ChannelName as the current Date everyday.
Can youtubeAPI help me with this problem?
I tried this out with Selenium. But it seems like it is impossible to login with a Browser which is opened remotely.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with the youtubeAPI, but anything can be done with an automated browser either coded by yourself or using whatever library you decide on.

Comment: Note also that you can only change your channel name three times every 90 days.